# The Membership.CreateUser() method in ASP.NET returns InvalidAnswer status all the time

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, createuser

I am using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider to implement user management in my ASP.NET website. I have set up the database and the forms to accept user input as well. Everything works fine when I call the below method.

```
Membership.CreateUser(txtUserID.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

with my web.config tag as below.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" applicationName="/" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"/>
```

But when I am trying out the overloaded method,

```
Membership.CreateUser(txtUserID.Text, txtPassword.Text, null, null, null, false, out status);
```

It doesn't work. I have changed my web.config to enable the overload as shown below.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="/" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" />
```

All I get is the status variable set to "InvalidAnswer". Though I am passing in a very valid answer to this method. Am i missing something here?

Comment: For some strange reason the web.config xml that I embed in the question is not visible.

Comment: I've fixed the xml problem now.